# Node - request - And Google URL shortener

Tags: node.js, google-url-shortener

So i got Google's URL shortener working on my Angular app however as it uses an API Key i thought it smarter/safer to do the google api call on my server side where I'm using Angular.

Found `$http` posts very straight forward with Angular however with Node i quickly realised I better use the npm package `request` however it doesn't seem to work.

So essentially I need to do:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url
Content-Type: application/json
{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}
```

And I've currently written:

```
//Load the request module
var request = require('request');

//Configure and make the request
request({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=XXXXXXXXX',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { //We can define headers too
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
        'longUrl': 'http://www.myverylongurl.com'
        }
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode, response.body);
        }
});
```

I keep getting the error:

```
"errors": [{ "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Required",    "locationType": "parameter”, “location": "resource.longUrl"   
}]
```

Is my request wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I've updated my question. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting access tokens? cf [authorizing requests](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#OAuth2Authorizing)

Comment: Nope  - the only identifier I'm using is the API Key

Comment: Read the document linked in previous comment. `Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported`. Yo umay want to use the Google API client module instead of request, it will facilitate the authorization process...

Comment: But doesn't that say `API key or an access token` - I used an API key in Angular and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes the API key is just fine. And you would get an other message if the problem was related to the authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [request documentation](https://github.com/request/request), you can post JSON data with the `json` option.

> json - sets body to JSON representation of value and adds Content-type: application/json header. Additionally, parses the response body as JSON.

In your case it would be:

```
request.post('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=xxxx', {
  json: {
    'longUrl': 'http://www.hugocaillard.com'
  }
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if(error) {
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log(response.statusCode, body)
  }
})
```

Note: you could also use the `request()` method (all I did was changing `data:`  with `json:`), but here `request.post()` works well enough.

Comment: Ahh - missed that!
Thanks

Comment: Yes it's not obvious in the `request` usage docs. You're welcome!